# The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, entity-framework-6, entitydatasource

when I want to configure my Datasource (EntityDataSource1) and assign the connectionString that is generated automatically by entity data model to it. I get the error:

"The metadata specified in the connection string could not be loaded. Consider rebuilding the web project to build assemblies that may contain metadata. 
The following error(s) occurred: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance".

I read so many suggestions like http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/
They all suggest to replace * with assembly-name in connection string. for example :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=
            res://*/Model.csdl|
            res://*/Model.ssdl|
            res://*/Model.msl;provider= <!-- ... -->
```

replace with

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=
            res://Simple Mvc.Data.dll/Model.csdl|
            res://Simple Mvc.Data.dll/Model.ssdl|
            res://Simple Mvc.Data.dll/Model.msl;provider= <!-- ... -->
```

my question is. Where can I find name of assembly? I installed .Net Reflector as well but i could not find the correct assembly name for entity data model.

Answer (score 15):

I found a solution for this error.

I keep my connectionString as same as before (I mean with *) then I opened the EDMX file with notepad and change ProviderManifestToken="2012" to ProviderManifestToken="2008"
That's it ;)

Now I can configure the EntityDataSourc with existing connectionString